# Book flip in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a book flip effect in jQuery, like [this one](http://www.coastworx.com/bookflip.php)

I thought it would be easy with jQuery, but when I tried to make the page turn effect, i realized that is quite complicated.

That is what i have:

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#s').click(function(){

            $('#flippage_0').animate({'width': '0'}, "fast", function(){
                $('#flippage_1').animate({'left': '0'}, "fast");
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="s" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:black;"></div>

<div id="book">
    <div id="flippage_0" class="flippage" >
        <div id="fliphtml_0" class="fliphtml" style="background-image:url('page0.jpg');z-index:3;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flippage_1" class="flippage">
        <div id="fliphtml_1" class="fliphtml" style="background-image:url('page1.jpg');z-index:2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flippage_2" class="flippage">
        <div id="fliphtml_2" class="fliphtml" style="background-image:url('page2.jpg');z-index:1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#book{

    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
    border-color: grey;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px 5px 3px 2px;
    height: 361px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.flippage{
    height: 361px;
    left: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;

}

.fliphtml{
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 361px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I made this code to make the flip effect, but if u check it, u will see that is quite different from the effect of the link above.

I searched for a tutorial on the internet, but all i have found are plugins without any explanation of how to make it.

Can anyone help me about how to make the book flip effect?

Thanks : )

Comment: why do you want to recreate it?? download the plugin

Answer (score 2):

Check this out and see if it works more like what you're going for...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/DkZsY/2/

EDIT: My original code was more basic but I was playing around some and added the reverse page flipping also.

```
$('.flippage').click(function(){

    $this = $(this);

    if ($(this).css('left') == '0px') {

            $(this).animate({ width: '0px', left: '300px' }, 100, function(){
                $this.next().width('0px').animate({
                    width: '300px'
                }, 150);
                $this.prev().animate({ width: '300px' }, 100);
                // replace left side with background
                $bg = $this.nextAll().eq(1).children('span').css('backgroundImage');
                $('#book').css('backgroundImage', $bg);

                $this.nextAll().eq(1).animate({
                    left: '0px',
                    width: '300px'
                }, 100, function() {
                    $('#book').css('backgroundImage', 'none');
                });
            });
    }
    else {

        if ($this.index() == 0) {
            //if last page (technically first div) then do nothing
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({ width: '0px' }, 100, function(){
                $this.prev().width('1px').animate({
                    left: '0px',
                    width: '300px'
                }, 100);
                $this.next().animate({ width: '0px' }, 100);
            });
        }
    }// end else
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I tried what u did but still doesnt work like a book flip. Anyway, will keep on thinking about the best way to do it ; )

Comment: @Alan Was just trying to give you the basic idea however I made some changes and added in photo images (instead of just using colors). I updated the demo link in the post. Looks like a pretty legit book now.

Comment: wdm, thanks a lot! Now the effect is much better ^_^ I'm going to take a look in the code to understand how u did it : )

Comment: wdm, I improved a little bit two thinks of your code:1. The first time you turn right page, the image of the left page changes from right to left. 2. when u turn left page, the left page is grey and then the page image appear. Thanks to your guidance, i got a nice effect: http://jsfiddle.net/wazH8/2/. The bad thing is that the effect is not still like a "book" itself. Need to show the left page during the effect when you turn right page . That is going to be difficult, but I'm going to try it : ) Thanks again!

Comment: @Alan Looks good, I would just speed up the effect. I created a delay variable in your code here so you can play with that setting easier: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/wazH8/8

Comment: @wdm I made the proper effect of the book turnning page (no dinamic code, just testing): http://jsfiddle.net/c2Ygs/ The turn right page effect is ok, but when i was making the turns left page, i couldnt animate the under page width from left to right U_U The only way i found is to animate left to 300px and width to 0px, but the effect becomes a litte weird. Do u know a way to animate the width to 0 from left to right in order to make the left page disappear at the same time that the right page is appearing in the right?

Comment: wdm thank you for this great lightweight plugin. Saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

You could look at the source code for the bookflip demo you linked to: coastworx.com/bookflip.js and try to replicate the mathematics in there. Then it should look pretty much the same.

Comment: Yes, actually I checked the lib and I was trying to understand the way it works. ^^